# How to display a standard object under a custom tab in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce

Create a new VisualForce page to display an object under custom tab.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?  Here's documentation on creating Tabs:  https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_web_tabs.htm